# How to make gif only loop once with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, image, gif

Here is my code

```
<Image
  resizeMode="contain"
  source={require('../../assets/splash.gif')}
  style={{ width: '100%', alignSelf: 'center' }}
/>
```

How can I control the gif to loop only once while first render? thanks.

Comment: Create a gif that doesn't loop?

Comment: I think you have to create a gif without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

use ControlledGifView component from react-native-controlled-gif library

[react-native-controlled-gif](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-controlled-gif)